# DatePicker Control Error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I needed to use datepicker control in my WPF application but I couldn't find this control in Toolbox. Then I installed WPFToolKit and added namespace in xaml file code but still it shows following error:


**Error   1   The tag 'DatePicker' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line 23 Position 18.  F:\Muhammad Anees\codereason_reports_v0.5_alpha\Samples\SimpleReport\EmployeeManager.xaml   23  18  Employee_Manager**

Here is my xaml file code:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleReport.EmployeeManager"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
Title="Employee Manager - Islam Engineering Pvt Ltd." Height="513" Width="865" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">

    <TabControl Height="482" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-2,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="832">
        <TabItem Header="Add New Employee" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid Width="806" Height="440">
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,14,0,0" Name="txtBarcode" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="#FFE0DECC" KeyUp="txtBarcode_KeyUp" />
                <Label Content="Employee ID:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,14,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,49,0,0" Name="emp_name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" IsEnabled="True" />
                <Label Content="Employee Name:" Height="28" Margin="19,0,676,365" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <Button Content="Add" Height="23" Name="addbtn" Width="75" Background="#FFD0B8B8" BorderBrush="#FFB19414" Margin="176,136,554,281" Click="addbtn_Click" />
                <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,78,0,0" Name="addmsg" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" Content="Employee added Successfully!" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Employee Attendance Report" Name="tabItem2">
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="Select Report Type:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,26,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" />
            <Button Background="#FFD0B8B8" BorderBrush="#FFB19414" Content="Generate Report" Height="23" Margin="152,157,557,270" Name="reportBtn" Click="button1_Click" />
            <RadioButton Content="Today's Report" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,31,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,26,0,0" Name="datePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" />
            <RadioButton Content="Previous Date" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,62,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <RadioButton Content="Within Range" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,95,0,0" Name="radioButton3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Remove Employee Record" Name="tabItem3">
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,26,0,0" Name="comboBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox3_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" />
                <Label Content="Select Employee ID:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,26,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" />
                <Button Background="#FFD0B8B8" BorderBrush="#FFB19414" Content="Remove" Height="23" Margin="181,80,566,347" Name="button2" Width="75" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

DatePicker Control is after second Radiobutton Control in above code.
Please tell me how to overcome this problem.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using WPF Toolkit, you need to use toolkit as you have specified that in the start for WPF toolkit Assembly

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,26,0,0" Name="datePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" />
```

Comment: Thank you It worked!
One more thing that I want to disable this datepicker control, how can i do that? I did this: datepicker1.IsEnabled = false but it won't work!!!

Answer (score 1):

IF this is the wpf toolkit from nuget then you call it like:

```
 <toolkit:DatePicker Name="blah blah" Margin="0" ect.. > </toolkit:DatePicker>
```

You may also have to try and clean and build the solution cause I actually got this error before to using the toolkit, but it worked after I rebuilt the solution.

Comment: Thank you It worked! One more thing that I want to disable this datepicker control, how can i do that? I did this: datepicker1.IsEnabled = false but it won't work!!!

Comment: It should be just a property within the control, you should just have to say: IsEnabled = false      without the the datepicker1.

Comment: So in the xaml, say: IsEnabled = "false". If you want to toggle the isenabled then you can make a property behind code and bind that property to the IsEnabled for ex/  IsEnabled = "{Binding EnabledOrNot}"

Comment: I did not get it completely. Can you please explain it with proper example? And i need to disable and enable datepicker control within the code not from property window!

Comment: If your using mvvm then you will need to bind to a property which I recommend. If not then you should be able to do it the way you had it above. Datapicker.IsEnabled = false. However you may have to reference the wpftoolkit in the code somehow. I'm not to sure. I always use mvvm pattern and bind all my properties so I'm not too familiar with the ole fashion way. Sorry. :(